Что указывает на John в примере?
Смотрите тут char* gg[] = {"John", "Maria"}; я хочу понять, если это массив указателей на строку то что указывает на John? Может быть на John указывает адрес её первого символа т.е J и gg[i] хранит адрес символа J, который указывает на строку John?

Что-то я ничего не понял, вы ж сами написали ответ в вопросе: если «это массив указателей», то значит на "John" указывает указатель, хранящийся в первом элементе этого массива. Ну и да, этот указатель указывает на первый символ строки

На строковый литерал John указывает gg[0] (можете считать, что по этому адресу в памяти находится массив char[5] = {'J', 'o', 'h', 'n', 0} из 5 байт). Далее можно сказать, что gg[0][2] == 'h' и т.д. и т.п.

@andreymal хм, сравните с похожим, до степени смешения, вариантом для C++14: auto gg[] = {"John"s, "Maria"s};, всё вроде так, да не так, поскольку получаем массив std::string.

@Serge3leo ну да, вы ж абсолютно другой код написали

"John" это безымянный массив char const [ 5 ], который хранится внутри кода программы. Можно написать char const ( * arraypointer ) [ 5 ] = & "John" ; , где arraypointer это указатель на данный массив. Или char const * letterpointer = "John" ; , где letterpointer указывает на первую букву данного массива.

Во первых, вы написали нехороший код. Литерал "John" имеет тип const char*, ему не место в массиве char*. Компиляторы C допускают такой код только из соображений обратной совместимости:
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char* gg[] = {"John", "Maria"};
}


$ gcc -Wwrite-strings example.c 
temp.c: In function ‘main’:
temp.c:8:19: warning: initialization discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
    8 |     char* gg[] = {"John", "Maria"};
      |                   ^~~~~~
temp.c:8:27: warning: initialization discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
    8 |     char* gg[] = {"John", "Maria"};
      |                           ^~~~~~~


Под капотом компилятор выделяет память под два массива символов. Они неизменямые:
const char john_array[5] = {'J', 'o', 'h', 'n', '\0'};
const char maria_array[6] = {'M', 'a', 'r', 'i', 'a', '\0'};

Каждому массиву сопоставляется указатель на первый символ массива:
const char *john_pointer = &john_array[0];
const char *maria_pointer = &maria_array[0];

Из указателей составляется массив gg:
const char* gg[] = {john_pointer, maria_pointer };


Литерал "John" имеет тип массива, и он автоматически иногда преобразуется на указатель на первую букву.

@AlexGlebe, я, кажется, так и написал. Или я где-то ошибся?

почитайте на комментарий в вопросе. Там всё подробнее и точнее.

@AlexGlebe, я прочёл комментарий, яснее не стало. Я, возможно, упускаю тонкости, которые вы видите ясно. Объясните.

вы по привычке указатель на один элемент называете массивом, но фактически это разные типы. просто дотошность это моя слабость. https://godbolt.org/z/5hqnffosE

@AlexGlebe, не совсем так. Я считаю что в этом процессе принимают участие три типа: сам тип массива, тип указателя на его первый элемент, и тип gg. Чтобы из типа массива получить тип указателя на его первый элемент, промежуточный тип указатель на массив в целом не нужен. Поэтому я его опускаю в выражении &john_array[0].

@AlexGlebe, &john_array[0] <-> &(john_array[0]). Указатель на массив не нужен.

@StanislavVolodarskiy а можно еще уточнить хоть и указатели не видны, но как бы в ["John] есть указатель, который указывает на него же ? Меня просто путает что указели, есть но они не видны в самом коде.

Внутри "John" есть пять байтов и больше ничего. Компилятор во время компиляции создаёт все эти дополнительные типы и указатели. В окончательную программу программу они не попадают. Туда попадает только то что упомянуто в коде: массив gg, внтури него два указателя на первые символы двух строк. Больше ничего, только три адреса.
